# Unable to Load tensorboard on local machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have been training an object detector using tensorflow on a Google cloud compute VM Instance. The event file required for tensorboard is being saved to the training directory. I have tried to access the event file using tensorboard, but have been unable to do so. I have SSH'd into the instance from the GCP console. The network is being trained in one SSH window and I have been trying to access tensorboard through a second SSH window into the VM instance.

I tried the following command for tensorboard;

```
tensorboard --logdir=='training' --host=127.0.0.1
```

gives an error

> Error: Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 6006. Ensure your server is listening on port 6006 and try again.

I have also tried

```
tensorboard --logdir=='training'
```

But this does not seem to work either.

```
tensorboard --logdir=='training' --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8080
```

gave a similar error

> Error: Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080. Ensure your server is listening on port 8080 and try again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but two thoughts:
1. Try using --host 0.0.0.0
2. You can copy the tensorboard files to a local computer and run tensorboard there. You can also connect to the VM using sshfs and establish the tensorboard log files directory as a remote file system on your local machine, and that way this directory gets updated locally automatically.